# Is Multi-Table Search Possible in with Texticle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, full-text-search, heroku

I want to do full-text search on classes with database relationships, such as:

`Class X
  has_many :y
 end`

`Class Y
  belongs_to :x
end`

My app is running on Heroku and I've investigated some options, such as Texticle, Tsearchable and acts-_as_tsearch, and I wanted to use Texticle but I can't seem to find if it supports Multi-Table/Multi-model search. Has anyone gotten that to work and if so, what is involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the best way is to use a search model as noted under the 'Systemwide Search' heading on the Textile page: http://tenderlove.github.com/texticle/